# Firebase FCM issue in WebLogic Server

Tags: java, spring, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, weblogic

I'm using firebase with spring mvc and i'm using WebLogic server. 
My firebase not working when i deploy on WebLogic server. 
if i run outside the server its work and my firebase fcm work.
Current i'm getting this error when i hit my server in weblogic server

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account: Hostname verification failed: HostnameVerifier=weblogic.security.utils.SSLWLSHostnameVerifier, hostname=oauth2.googleapis.com
```

> 2021-01-14 17:33:04,348 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue:
> 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] ERROR
> c.e.c.m.c.NotificationControllerWS - failed to send notification
> com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingException: Error while
> calling FCM backend service
> at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.sendAll(FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.java:141)
> at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$2.execute(FirebaseMessaging.java:293)
> at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$2.execute(FirebaseMessaging.java:290)
> at com.google.firebase.internal.CallableOperation.call(CallableOperation.java:36)
> at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.sendAll(FirebaseMessaging.java:183)
> at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.sendMulticast(FirebaseMessaging.java:252)
> at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.sendMulticast(FirebaseMessaging.java:227)
> at com.etisalat.cim.mobileWalletAdapter.controller.NotificationControllerWS.pushNotificationToMobileApp(NotificationControllerWS.java:97)
> at com.etisalat.cim.mobileWalletAdapter.controller.NotificationControllerWS.pushNotifications(NotificationControllerWS.java:78)
> at com.etisalat.cim.mobileWalletAdapter.controller.NotificationControllerWS$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$898ae6ca.invoke()
> at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:669)
> at com.etisalat.cim.mobileWalletAdapter.controller.NotificationControllerWS$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$56284e04.pushNotifications()
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
> at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115)
> at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
> at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
> at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:167)
> at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
> at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:122)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
> at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
> at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
> at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
> at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
> at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
> at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service
> account: Hostname verification failed:
> HostnameVerifier=weblogic.security.utils.SSLWLSHostnameVerifier,
> hostname=oauth2.googleapis.com.
> at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:360)
> at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:165)
> at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:151)
> at com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter.initialize(HttpCredentialsAdapter.java:96)
> at com.google.firebase.internal.FirebaseRequestInitializer.initialize(FirebaseRequestInitializer.java:55)
> at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingClientImpl$1.initialize(FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.java:220)
> at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:88)
> at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildPostRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:128)
> at com.google.api.client.googleapis.batch.BatchRequest.execute(BatchRequest.java:216)
> at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.sendBatchRequest(FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.java:168)
> at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.sendAll(FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.java:137)
> ... 102 common frames omitted Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: Hostname verification failed:
> HostnameVerifier=weblogic.security.utils.SSLWLSHostnameVerifier,
> hostname=oauth2.googleapis.com.
> at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.doPostHandshake(JaSSLEngine.java:677)
> at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.doAction(JaSSLEngine.java:748)
> at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.unwrap(JaSSLEngine.java:132)
> at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.unwrap(JSSEFilterImpl.java:603)
> at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.unwrapAndHandleResults(JSSEFilterImpl.java:507)
> at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:96)
> at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:75)
> at weblogic.socket.JSSESocket.startHandshake(JSSESocket.java:219)
> at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:563)
> at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:534)
> at weblogic.net.http.HttpsURLConnection.connect(HttpsURLConnection.java:248)
> at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:341)
> at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:108)
> at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:79)
> at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:995)
> at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:358)
> ... 112 common frames omitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable WebLogic's hostname verifyer. Read this [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/cloudadapter-eloqua/ELCUG/GUID-590869CA-512F-4848-856A-503EF1D6EF39.htm#ELCUG-GUID-590869CA-512F-4848-856A-503EF1D6EF39) to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for help @Emmanuel Collin its work for me